# UIImagePickerController dismiss not properly

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, dismiss

There are 5 items in UITabbarController: VC0, VC1, VC3(default selected), VC4, VC5.

UITabbarController > NavigationController > VC1 > VC1-A

UIImagePickerController is presented in VC1-A:

```
let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
imagePickerController.delegate = self
imagePickerController.allowsEditing = false
self.present(imagePickerController, animated: false)

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    let info = convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKeyDictionary(info)

    if let image = info[convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage)] as? UIImage{
       topImage.image = image
    }

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

When image is selected and the picker is dismissed, the view will go to the default selected item  VC3, but not VC1-A.

I found this in a resent test on App, but I remember it worked properly before. I now cannot recall what I did that may make it not proper, Xcode update, Swift version update? I do know that I make no change on this part.

The following tries not work either:

```
self.navigationController?.present(imagePickerController, animated: false)
self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
picker.popViewController(animated: true)
```

By now I make it works like this:

```
picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
    })
```

But it's not a good idea to solve the problem, hope someone can give a proper solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get tabBarController of VC1-A's navigation controller and change selected index

```
picker.dismiss(animated: true) {//dismiss image picker
    if let navigationController = self.navigationController {
        navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)//go to VC1
        navigationController.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2//go to VC3
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought that I somehow had written some bad codes to make it fails, there is no way to simply use `dismiss`? I remember it worked before :-(

Comment: @jdleung try `self.navigationController?.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2`

Comment: @jdleung Did you try this?

Comment: By now it works: if let tbc = self.tabBarController{ tbc.selectedIndex = 1 }, the screen now stays at VC3 for about 0.3 sec before goes to VC1-A. I'm looking for the simplest way, and also want to find out why `picker.dismiss(animated: true' worked before?

Comment: @jdleung just try `picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
        self.navigationController.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
}`

Comment: It works, but the screen stays at VC3 for a while(although a fleeting glimpse) before back to VC1-A, is there any other direct way to just dismiss? Did I make wrong presenting? I tried to set the segue as `show detail`, it's dismissed well, but it did not inherit its topViewController's navigationBar.